# Download multiple files from a document library using firefox,chrome or safari. as seems the "Open in explorer" will be disabled on non-IE browsers

Tags: 2013, document-library, library, configuration, ie

I have a Document library inside a Team site collection on sharepoint server 2013. now our customer asked us if there is a way to download multiple files at once from the document library. now i can following these 2 steps:-

1. under "Library" tab >> "Open with explorer".
2. or i can click on "New document" >> "upload files using Windows Explorer instead "

but some of our users are using Firefox, chrome & safari, and seems the above 2 options are not available on non-IE browses. so for those users who are using non-IE browsers is there a way to download multiple files at once ??

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The only other way would be to map the document library as a network location. The basics steps to do this are:

- Open Windows Explorer
- Right click Computer and then click "Add a network location"
- Click Next until the "Specify the location of your website" page
- Enter the URL to your document library, e.g. https://example.com/sites/bobssite/Shared%20Documents, and click Next
- Give this network location a name, E.g. Bob's Shared Docs
- Click Next, then Finish

You should now see this network location in Windows Explorer. This would be especially helpful if your users needed to upload/download multiple files regularly. If your users aren't going to be doing this regularly, it might just be easier for them to open the document library in Internet Explorer.

Comment: i thought there is a way similar to "open with explorer" to do so on non-IE browsers